# RK4 for Van der Pol MatLab

Tags: matlab, runge-kutta-methods

I'm trying to implement RK algorithm applied to Van Der Pol equation. 
I tried this code

```
y = zeros(n, 2);
y(1, 1) = y0(1);
y(1, 2) = y0(2);

% Van der Pol equation 
% y''(t) - (1 - y^2(t)) * y'(t) + y(t) = 0;
% y'(t)  = y(2)
% y''(t) = (1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)

for i = 1:n-1
    k1 = h*(y(i,2));
    k2 = h*(y(i,2)+0.5*k1);
    k3 = h*(y(i,2)+0.5*k2);
    k4 = h*(y(i,2)+k3);
    y(i+1,1) = y(i,1)+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;

    y1 = y(i,1);
    y2 = y(i,2);
    k1 = h*((1-y1^2)*y2-y1);

    y1 = y(i,1)+0.5*k1;
    y2 = y(i,2)+0.5*k1;
    k2 = h*((1-y1^2)*y2-y1);

    y1 = y(i,1)+0.5*k2;
    y2 = y(i,2)+0.5*k2;
    k3 = h*((1-y1^2)*y2-y1);

    y1 = y(i,1)+k3;
    y2 = y(i,2)+k3;
    k4 = h*((1-y1^2)*y2-y1);

    y(i+1,2) = y(i,2)+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
end
```

Trying to give different `h, t_end, y0` as input but with

```
plot(y)
```

I never get a chaotic plot.

Source of the code: [GitHub code](https://github.com/jkurdel/runge-kutta-neural-network/blob/master/matlab/rk_van_der_pol.m)

Comment: are you certain that the initial condition is one that leads to chaotic behavior

Comment: What is the differential equation (or system of equations) you are trying to solve with this code?  What if you replaced these equations by simple harmonic motion?  Would the code work as expected?  Did you look over the code and do you understand what it is doing?

Comment: @phdmba7of12  it doesn't depend only on initial condition but also on other costants (thah honestly i don't found on this code and i don't know how to implement), but i only found this code online to apply rk to van der pol in matlab

Comment: Please find a book, such as "Numerical Recipes" by Press, et al. and look up fourth-order Runge-Kutta methods.

Comment: Looks like the code first finds $y_{1,i+1}$ from $y_{1,i}$ and then finds $y_{2,i+1}$ from both $y_{1,i}$ and $y_{2,i}$.  Is that how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement RK4 code [for the the coupled system as a coupled system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29830807/3088138). You can avoid the code bloat that would usually imply [by utilizing the vector capabilities of the MATrix LABoratory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1702161/115115)

But staying with the component-wise code you should get

```
y1 = y(i,1); v1 = y(i,2)
k1y = h*v1;
k1v = h*((1-y1^2)*v1 - y1);

y2 = y1 + 0.5*k1y; v2 = v1 + 0.5*k1v;
k2y = h*v2;
k2v = h*((1-y2^2)*v2 - y2);

y3 = y1 + 0.5*k2y; v3 = v1 + 0.5*k2v;
k3y = h*v3;
k3v = h*((1-y3^2)*v3 - y3);

y4 = y1 + k3y; v4 = v1 + k3v;
k4y = h*v4;
k4v = h*((1-y4^2)*v4 - y4);

y(i+1,1) = y(i,1)+(k1y+2*k2y+2*k3y+k4y)/6;
y(i+1,2) = y(i,2)+(k1v+2*k2v+2*k3v+k4v)/6;
```

etc.

Note that the Van der Pol oscillator is an oscillator, that it, is has a limit cycle which is a deformation of the circle of radius $2$. If you want a halfway chaotic plot, you should implement the Lorenz system.